# use video for demo player is it legal?

Tags: video, copyright, legal

My question is about copyright of videos.
I want to use [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AByfaYcOm4A) inside my demo web base video player,but i do not know any thing law of copyright or license of video. how can i check for this video license ?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not look around for some Creative Commons material?

Comment: I am Really with zero details,
How Can Do it ?

Comment: ahem. http://bit.ly/1axI8VW

Comment: Check [Blender Institute's Open Projects](http://www.blender.org/features/projects/). They are licensed under Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 license. You can use and distribute those films by providing a credit to Blender Institute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything published anywhere is automatically copyrighted, with all rights reserved to the author or publisher. The source of this video is known, so your obvious choice here is to contact the publisher and ask permission.

This is a promotional video, so it's very possible that they will permit your use, with proper attribution or for a small fee. But you have to ask, and they have to agree, for your use to be legitimate.

Comment: Anything captured anywhere is automatically copyrighted.  Publishing is not generally a requirement.

Comment: Right, the requirement is only that it be fixed in a tangible medium. My point was that since this HAS been published, you can be certain that it's copyrighted, absent a notice to the contrary.

Comment: Oh yes, not disagreeing with you, just wanted to make sure that the OP or future users realized that it would be copy-written even if it was unpublished.

Answer (score 1):

Often short clips for demonstration purposes qualify as fair use, however you can't generally use more than a few seconds.  Even video clips that have been released on the Internet are not necessarily safe to use as the content may still require you to have a license.  Your best bet is to contact a lawyer since fair use varies greatly from jurisdiction to jurisdiction or look for content that is released under an open license such as creative commons.